# Understanding C x86 optimization of a small function

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, strict-aliasing

I have a relatively small C function.

```
#define ROTL16(x, r) (((x) << (r)) | (x >> (16 - (r))))

void a_inverse(uint16_t *left, uint16_t *right) {
  *right ^= *left;
  *right = ROTL16(*right, 14);
  *left -= *right;
  *left = ROTL16(*left, 7);
}
```

The function was called by submitting `uint16_t` pointers that point to low and hight 16-bit of a single `uint32_t` integer.

```
uint32_t whole;
uint16_t * left = (uint16_t *)&whole;
uint16_t * right = left + 1;

a_inverse(left, right);
```

But the function does not perform as expected.
So I blindly add the volatile keyword.

```
#define ROTL16(x, r) (((x) << (r)) | (x >> (16 - (r))))

void a_inverse(volatile uint16_t *left, volatile uint16_t *right) {
  *right ^= *left;
  *right = ROTL16(*right, 14);
  *left -= *right;
  *left = ROTL16(*left, 7);
}
```

This time it works correctly.

Comparing the output assembly with -O3 I see nothing wrong

This is a non-volatile version

```
a_inverse:
  .cfi_startproc
  endbr64
  movzwl    (%rsi), %ea
  xorw  (%rdi), %ax
  rorw  $2, %ax
  movw  %ax, (%rsi)
  movzwl    (%rdi), %edx
  subl  %eax, %edx
  movl  %edx, %eax
  rolw  $7, %ax
  movw  %ax, (%rdi)
  ret
  .cfi_endproc
```

And this is the one with `volatile` keyword

```
a_inverse:
  .cfi_startproc
  endbr64
  movzwl    (%rdi), %edx
  movzwl    (%rsi), %eax
  xorl  %edx, %eax
  movw  %ax, (%rsi)
  movzwl    (%rsi), %eax
  movzwl    (%rsi), %edx
  sall  $14, %eax
  shrw  $2, %dx
  orl   %edx, %eax
  movw  %ax, (%rsi)
  movzwl    (%rsi), %edx
  movzwl    (%rdi), %eax
  subl  %edx, %eax
  movw  %ax, (%rdi)
  movzwl    (%rdi), %eax
  movzwl    (%rdi), %edx
  sall  $7, %eax
  shrw  $9, %dx
  orl   %edx, %eax
  movw  %ax, (%rdi)
  ret
  .cfi_endproc
```

And I don't understand why do the functions behave differently.

Could you help me understand what the reason might be?
The only difference in expected/unexpected results is those `volatile` usages.
Removing either one of the `volatile` would result in an unexpected result.

Comment: How did you determine that "the function does not perform as the expectation"?

Comment: Just to be paranoid (I don't see how this comes into play here), I would suggest changing the macro to `#define ROTL16(x, r) (((x) << (r)) | ((x) >> (16 - (r))))`

Comment: It is a part of cryptographic operations that comes with test vectors.

Comment: Are you sure `left` and `right` are next to each other and not accidentally overlapping? How do you pass the input in? Make sure the `+ 1` is not in bytes.

Comment: I casted it from `uint_32_t` like this: `uint16_t *left = (uint16_t *)whole; uint16_t *right = left + 1;`. Also if it is the overlapping issue the `volatile` keyword would not make it any better.

Comment: Then you have a strict-aliasing violation, with undefined behavior as a result.  That might or might not explain the difference, but since you're using GCC, you could try compiling the first version with `-fno-strict-aliasing` to see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: I am inclined to guess that the problem is actually in the caller.  The compiler (without `-fno-strict-aliasing`) might assume, based on type analysis, that the call to `a_inverse()` cannot modify the value of `whole`, and perform optimizations depending on that for correctness.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that solves the problem but could you put it as an answer, and maybe adding some more info.

Comment: You need to provide a full program that can reproduce the result you're seeing, specifically an [mcve], before anyone can properly answer your question.

Comment: @RossRidge I just update the question to include info on the caller side. I did not include it at first because it seems irrelevant, at least from the changes I can observe.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is unlikely to be in function `a_inverse()` itself, and the fact that `volatile`-qualifying the arguments changed the behavior is a happenstance if the data are not actually volatile.

In all likelihood, the locus of the problem is actually in the caller.  Indeed, in comments, you describe computing the argument pointers something like this:

```
uint32_t *whole = ...;
uint16_t *left = (uint16_t *) whole;
uint16_t *right = left + 1;
```

which would presumably be followed up by a call such as

```
a_inverse(left, right);
```

.  The cast to type `uint16_t *` is permitted.  The permissibility of the pointer arithmetic is debatable, but in practice it is unlikely to be an issue.  But because the resulting `left` and `right` pointers don't actually point to `uint16_t` objects, attempting to use them to access the object to which they point violates the strict aliasing rule (C18, paragraph 6.5/7), and therefore produces undefined behavior.

The strict aliasing rule says that an object can be accessed only via an lvalue of compatible type +/- qualification and signedness differences, possibly in a union, or via an lvalue of character type.  (Among the key implications of the latter is that you may access any object's representation via a `char *`.)  This allows compilers to use data-type analysis to inform optimization choices.

GCC has a flag, `-fno-strict-aliasing`, that tells it not to use type analysis to make optimization decisions -- basically, forcing it to assume that any pointer might alias any other.  If you don't want to fix the issue then using that flag would likely mitigate it.

On the other hand, I suspect that all the pointer (mis)use is a misguided attempt at optimization.  I would rewrite the function without:

```
uint32_t a_inverse(uint32_t whole) {
    uint16_t left = whole;  // x86 is little-endian
    uint16_t right = whole >> 16;

    right ^= left;
    right  = ROTL16(right, 14);
    left  -= right;
    left   = ROTL16(left, 7);

    return right << 16 + left;
}
```

... and expect it to be at least as fast, not least because there are no aliasing risks to limit available optimizations.